# Cef4delphi calls chromium.Loadurl() to cause the program to top

Tags: cef4delphi

In Delphi rad studio 10.3, I use cef4delphi to call chromium.Loadurl() or chromium.Browser.Mainframe.Loadurl(), which will cause the top of the program. How can I solve it

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TfrmFatchView.Chromium_OnLoadingStateChange(Sender: TObject; const
  browser: ICefBrowser; isLoading, canGoBack, canGoForward: Boolean);
begin
  FChromium.DefaultWindowInfoExStyle := FChromium.DefaultWindowInfoExStyle;

end;

procedure TfrmFatchView.Chromium_OnSetFocus(Sender: TObject; const browser:
    ICefBrowser; source: TCefFocusSource; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: Can you add some text explaning what this does?